# Databinding ColorStateList

Tags: android

I am using an open source component called MaterialProgressBar which has a tint attribute called **mpb_progressTint** that is defined as a ColorStateList.  I am using databinding but am unable to set the value with the following error:

> msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:mpb_progressTint' with parameter type int on me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar.

Here is my XML:

```
<me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Horizontal.NoPadding"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:max="@{vm.max}"
        android:progress="@{vm.progress}"
        android:visibility="@{vm.isComplete ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE }"
        app:mpb_progressTint="@{vm.isDownloading ? @color/my_blue : @color/my_gray}"
        app:mpb_progressStyle="horizontal"
        app:mpb_showTrack="false"
        app:mpb_useIntrinsicPadding="false"
        />
```

Comment: got a link to the source/docs for MaterialProgressBar? Might help figure out what's up.

Comment: https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar

Comment: mpb_progressTint is defined in attrs.xml as: <attr name="mpb_progressTint" format="color|reference" />

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect attribute **app:mpb_progressTint** with 
appropriate setter method from MaterialProgressBar class. You can do it by adding to your Activity or Fragment or any other class annotations:

```
@BindingMethods({
    @BindingMethod(type = me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar.class,
           attribute = "app:mpb_progressTint",
           method = "setProgressTintList") })
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   // your activity body here

}
```